# asp.net mvc pass a variable to another action method with a form post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page. (action) and a controller called Widget. im passing in client as a string.

I want to be able to pass in the client from one page to the next, as well as the other fields posted.

what am i doing wrong below? client is coming up as null

eg: Widet/Page2/clientABC

```
        public ActionResult Page2(string client)
        {

            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Page2(string client, string sector)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Page3", new { client = client, sector = sector });
        }

        public ActionResult Page3(string client, string sector)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Widet/Page2?client=clientABC&sector=123
```

Since you have an action with multiple parameters, I think you need to name them in the query string. That's how I've done it. Unless the action has a single parameter, the default routing doesn't handle the way you are trying to call it.

Look in your Global.asax.cs file to see the routing config.

If it looks like this:

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Root",
          "",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
    }
```

You could fiddle with it and make it support multiple params like:

```
{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}
```

Though I would just use named parameters in the query string.

Comment: Remove [AcceptVerbs] or add HttpVerbs.Get and it should work. Works for me: http://localhost/Document/Page2?client=abc&sector=123

Comment: it worked by changing the route to match mine: {controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right your problem is that you don't post the client to your "Page2" action. You can ether post it as a post parameter (in a hidden field for example) or in the url (in the action of your form tag). My guess is that you want it in your url.

If you use the form html helper you can use it like this:

```
<%using(Html.BeginForm("Page2", "Home", new { client = "clientABC" })) { } %>
```